# copying a custom object

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have an object called Layer that has some attributes and some methodes.

i need to pass Layer to a second view controller:

```
SecondVC *view = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"2VC"];
view.Layer = [[Layer alloc] initWithMapLayer:self.Layer];
view.delegate = self;

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:view];
navController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;

[self presentModalViewController:navController animated:YES];
```

in the SecondVC, i may change the attributes. I then return the Layer object back via a delegate;

```
-(void)done
{
    [self.delegate returnLayer:self.layer];

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

now my problem is that i am passing a pointer to my first view controller's Layer object and when i update the Layer in the second view controller, my first view controller's Layer object is also being updated.

because of this, i can't tell if it has been changed (if it has, i need to run some code).

how can i create a copy of my Layer object and pass that instead of a pointer to my first view controller's Layer object?

EDIT:

i did try use a second init method:

```
-(id)initWithLayer:(Layer *)Layer
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        self.call = [[FunctionCall alloc] init];        
        self.HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] init];

        self.Layers = [[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:Layer.Layers] copy];
        self.nameList = [[NSArray arrayWithArray:Layer.nameList] copy];
    }
    return self;
}
```

which did not work out.

EDIT2:

tried

```
Layer *copyLayer = [self.myLayer copy];

layerView.myLayer = copyLayer;
```

and got error

```
-[layer copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xfc72c40
2012-06-12 11:15:28.584 Landscout[8866:1fb07] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Layer copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xfc72c40'
```

SOLVED:

i added a deep copy to the initWithLayer method:

```
for (id key in layer.layers)
{
    [newLayers setValue:[[layer.layers objectForKey:key] mutableCopy] forKey:[key mutableCopy]];
}

for (id name in layer.nameList)
{
    [newList addObject:[name mutableCopy]];
}
```

this gives me a copy of the Layer object

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to implement `copy` function to your object

In your Layer.m

```
- (id)copy
{
    Layer *layerCopy = [[Layer alloc] init];

    //YOu may need to copy these values too, this is a shallow copy
    //If YourValues and someOtherValue are only primitives then this would be ok
    //If they are objects you will need to implement copy to these objects too
    layerCopy.YourValues = self.YourValues;
    layerCopy.someOtherValue = self.someOtherValue;

    return layerCopy;
}
```

Now in your calling function

```
//instead of passing self.Layer pass [self.Layer copy]
view.Layer = [[Layer alloc] initWithMapLayer:[self.Layer copy]];
```

Comment: ok, i tried doing this with an different init call. my attributes are a Dictionary and an array. i'd need to do a deep copy of the dictionary?

Comment: `-copy` will copy everything in the dictionary.  I would copy everything, rather than just set it to the same pointers.  So do this:`layerCopy.YourValues = [self.YourValues copy];`

Comment: Justin, do you mean the copy method Omar created or the objective c key word copy?

Comment: all `NSObject`s implement `-copy`  in fact, you may not even need to implement copy in your subclass, it may work without writing it out, I think it would just inherit it from `NSObject`, I am not sure though.

Comment: Have you tried passing something like `layerCopy = [self.layer copy];`?

Comment: just tried, got an error: *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[MapLayer copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xfc72c40'

Comment: Should probably implement the [`NSCopying`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSCopying_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) protocol as well.

Comment: @FreeAsInBeer it seems so, but strange, he should be able to just send a copy message

Comment: @OmarAbdelhafith: It is common practice to implement the `NSCopying` protocol, but it's also common to implement the additional `copy` method for convenience. I believe it's just an alias for `copyWithZone:` ([Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSObject/copy)).

Comment: tried adding the NSCopying delegate, get the same error when trying to copy Layer object.

Comment: Ok, i just implemented a deep copy in initWithLayer: and it works.